# "Cogs" startup problem

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, games, opengl

When I try to run the game *Cogs* from the command line, the game spits out the following error and dies immediately:

```
Couldn't set 800x600 OpenGL video mode: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix this?

Edit: I have an intel graphics card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem (different resolution in my case: 1366x768);

The solution was to edit the following file: `~/.local/share/Cogs/cogs.ini`
(you can see the Windows origins of this game from the file and the path);

Play with the settings there - I would set resolution to 0, and all visual effects to minimum to get it running - then you can always open the settings window and change them to something better.

The minimalistic file looks like this:

```
VolumeMusic 0.044484
VolumeEffects 0.750000
EnableShadows false
EnableFilters false
Fullscreen false
IntervalImmediate true
Resolution 0
WindowPosX 0
WindowPosY 0
Antialiasing 0
Language english
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been reported as being fixed in nvidia v280 if you are using a nvidia card. If so, you can try installing those drivers instead of your current ones.

Comment: I have an intel card, but +1 because this information is useful to those who do have nvidia cards.